# Overriding Bootstrap classes in CodePen site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding, codepen

I have free account on CodePen. In my code I use Bootstrap but I also override some Bootstrap classes in the CodePen CSS editor. In the `head` tag of HTML editor, I defined the loading order:

```html
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" <br>
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css"
```

I.e. my `custom.css` I must override the Bootstrap classes. But it does not work in the CodePen editor. I have to use the `!important` rule to override Bootstrap classes too many.

The main thing is my code works perfectly in Google Chrome and Firefox without using the `!important` rule when I open `custom.html` on my local computer.

Why does not it work in the CodePen editor and why does it make such a big difference?

Comment: please share your codepen

Comment: Have a look on at the Chrome dev tools. The styles will be orderd to be most specific to least specific so you can see which ones take precendence over others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760105/see-exact-css-specificity-in-chrome-dev-tools

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide enough information for us to help. In this case, your actual CSS seems relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the order is :

1. `!important`
2. inline style
3. `<style>` in the html part
4. style in the css part
5. style in css settings.

If you want to avoid adding `!important`, you should add your link in the settings.

Go to the Settings -> css-> ->Add External Stylesheets/Pens -> add you css link -> save & close.

([Codepen link](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/qBKWJNq))

Comment: Thanks. I decided it by settings in CodePen.